# Lync PowerShell: Enable a User for Enterprise Voice

Tags: c#, shell, pipeline, lync

I have the below code used for enabling a user for Lync using Power Shell commands. The code has two steps, the first one is to enable the user, the second one is to enable Enterprise Voice.

```
 using (Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline())
 {
     var enableCsUser = new Command("Enable-CsUser");
     enableCsUser.Parameters.Add("Identity", upn);
     enableCsUser.Parameters.Add("SipAddress", "sip:" + sipAddress);
     enableCsUser.Parameters.Add("RegistrarPool", LyncPool);
     pipe.Commands.Add(enableCsUser);
     InvokePipeline(pipe);
 }
 using (Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline())
 {
     var setCsUser = new Command("Set-CsUser");
     setCsUser.Parameters.Add("Identity", upn);
     setCsUser.Parameters.Add("EnterpriseVoiceEnabled", true);
     pipe.Commands.Add(setCsUser);
     InvokePipeline(pipe);
 }
```

The first part works fine and the user is enabled. the second part throws an exception at `InvokePipeline(pipe);` with no clear reason for me. I've followed the following articles [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398510.aspx), [here](http://allunifiedcom.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/usingpowershell-to-enable-users-for-lync-and-exchange-unified-messaging/) and [here](http://gotspeechguy.com/2011/09/07/lync-powershell-enable-a-user-for-enterprise-voice/).

The exception details are below.

```
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Management object not found for identity "lfigo@fabrekam.cloudyCloud.com".
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TOutput](IEnumerable input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
at System.Management.Automation.RemotePipeline.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that I use. Works fine...Note that passing a simple ...Parameters.Add("EnterpriseVoiceEnabled", true) does NOT work. Have to imbed the CommandParameter inside the Paramater.

```
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command enable_telephone = new Command(@"Set-CsUser");
pipeline.Commands.Add(enable_telephone);
enable_telephone.Parameters.Add("Identity", Account1.Text);
enable_telephone.Parameters.Add("LineUri", "tel:" + phone_number);
enable_telephone.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("EnterpriseVoiceEnabled", true));
pipeline.Invoke();
```

Comment: I'm using the following: `ps.AddParameter("EnterpriseVoiceEnabled", "$True");` which achieves the same.

Comment: The OP doesn't say what his situation is, but just using "$true" won't work if you are running the code remotely (not on Lync server). You have to use the parameter definition inside the other for remote execution.